# ElasticSearch: how to search from multiple indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I have a situation where I need to search from multiple indexes (products and users). Below is a sample query I am using to do that search

```
http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?q=*wood*
http://localhost:9200/users,products/_search?q=*wood*
```

With the above API request, it only returns search results for the product index. But if I search using the below API it returns search results for users index

```
http://localhost:9200/users/_search?q=*wood*
```

As you can see I am passing same value for "q" parameter. I need to search for both product and users index and check if there is the word "wood" in any attribute in both indexes. How can I achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple index names instead of `_all` as it will search in other indices that you don't intent to by using the comma seprated index name like

```
http://localhost:9200/users,products/_search?q=*wood*
```

Although, `_all` should also fetch the result from `users` index which you get when you specify its name, you need to debug why its happening, maybe increase the `size` param to 1000 as by default Elasticsearch returns only 10 results and it seems in case of `_all` all the top results coming from `products` index only.

Comment: With that also i am getting the same results - search results only for products. And at the moment there is only these two indexes

Comment: @pavithrarox added more info to my answer that would help you to know the cause

Comment: @pavithrarox, can you upvote as well, and glad it was helpful to you :)

Comment: Yes. the issue was with the size parameter. it was set to 100 but seems like there are more products that match the search results than that.